# Creating a new raster image from averages

Tags: r, average, raster

I have a long list of rasters and I need to take an average of a certain number and create a new image.  For example, if I have rasters r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8
I want to take an average of r1 and r2 to give me an image, lets say new1. Then I want an average of r3 and r4 to give me image new2.  I tried using the runmean in caTools but I couldn't get the output I needed.  If I have 8 raster images then using a window of two should leave me with four raster images.  I know raster usually belong on the GIS site but I needed help with the code so I hope it is ok here.

Comment: You are looking for the `overlay` function of the `raster` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have all the rasters in one folder: rasdir (and nothing else in this folder but the rasters to loop over), set environmental vars:

```
rasdir="myrasters/"
raspaths <- list.files(path=rasdir, full.names=T)
```

Assuming all rasters have the same extent and resolution, they can be stacked:

```
rascube <- stack(raspaths)
```

Create function that executes some function e.g. mean across bands

`rascube` is the stack of images to loop over, `win` the window size and `outdir` is the output directory

````
rasfun <- function(x=rascube, win=2, outdir=getwd()){

#Sanity check
if(!(length(raspaths)/win)%%1==0){stop("Number of rasters must be divisible by window size")}

#Create ```mat``` , an index that determines how rasters in ```rascube``` are aggregated: 
#indices in the same row refer to rasters to be averaged into the ith output.

mat <- matrix(data=1:length(raspaths), ncol=win, byrow=T)

#Loop over ```rascube```, calculating the moving average as controlled by ```mat```

for (i in 1:nrow(mat)){

#Compute ith moving mean, You can alter this to compute a moving "whatever you like"
#Note the usage of ```[[ ]]``` to subset raster bands: see ```raster``` docu.
#Also Note the usage of ```na.rm=T```, just in case your images have NA's you dont care about

res_i <- sum(x[[ mat[i,1]:mat[i,win] ]], na.rm=T)/win #

#Write output to file: note how output filename is derived from the respective input rasters
#makes it possible to trace the outputs back to their source rasters.

writeRaster(x=res_i, filename=paste(mat[i,1:win], collapse=""),
format="GTiff", overwrite=T)

}
}

#Run newly created function on your stack of inputs with whatever args:
rasfun(x=rascube, win=2, outdir="moving_mean_rasters/")
````

Note: the number of rasters must be divisible by the window size e.g. attempting to run a moving window computation on 7 rasters with a window size of 2 will be made to fail by the sanity check. Of course you can alter the function to behave as you think is best for your use case. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.  I had the for loop going through and essentially doing a running average but it was the matrix determining the aggregation that I couldn't figure out.